# Serving images from s3 with Cache-Control header distributed with CloudFront not caching?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am serving static images from an S3 bucket and adding a header of `Cache-Control: public,max-age=31557600` to all assets in the bucket.  The assets are then distributed via cloudfront.  Here are the headers in the browser:

```
Request URL: cloudfront url here
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address: remote address
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 14:00:27 GMT
ETag: "871e4a2d65f891b79a30b1fdf7622650"
Server: AmazonS3
Age: 52182
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 f348970492a18bf5c630c5acc86c1ee3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: u35A-l_zhEAMsJSmtLmf4VFIPfBfDLdBqIjdjwfAJSDBcJhxLC7OdA==
```

I am unsure about what to make out of this.  I believe `hit from cloudfront` means that the edge servers are caching my assets.  Does this mean that CloudFront has obeyed the `Cache-Control` headers being sent from S3, and these images are being cached in CloudFront edge servers?  Or are the images being cached in the broswer?  I appreciate any help with elucidating my confusion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two headers to look at when determining if cloudfront is caching.

- hit means is was served from cache.  If you see miss, it went to the origin
- age, how many seconds the object has been in cache.

Based on those to headers, yes, cloudfront is caching your content as you asked by setting cache-control headers.

Comment: Additonally, `304 Not Modified` means the browser already has a local copy that matches what's in the CloudFront cache, and didn't download it again from CloudFront, because CloudFront told the browser the object had not been modified since its previous successful download attempt.